# Creating a dynamically canvas from a string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create graphic elements from deserialization. I can serialize my canvas and its children in a XML and retrieve it in a string. The content look like this (Xaml serialization) in the string :

```
<Canvas
  Background="#00FFFFFF"
  Name="overlay"
  Width="1042"
  Height="669"
  Panel.ZIndex="2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Path
    Stroke="#FFFF0000"
    StrokeThickness="4">
    <Path.Data>
      <LineGeometry
        StartPoint="348,190"
        EndPoint="407,321" />
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path
    Stroke="#FFFF0000"
    StrokeThickness="4">
    <Path.Data>
      <LineGeometry
        StartPoint="567,132"
        EndPoint="586,284" />
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path
    Stroke="#FFFF0000"
    StrokeThickness="4">
    <Path.Data>
      <LineGeometry
        StartPoint="299,425"
        EndPoint="553,390" />
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path
    Stroke="#FFFF0000"
    StrokeThickness="4">
    <Path.Data>
      <LineGeometry
        StartPoint="653,315"
        EndPoint="539,424" />
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path
    Stroke="#FFFF0000"
    StrokeThickness="4">
    <Path.Data>
      <LineGeometry
        StartPoint="432,464"
        EndPoint="685,439" />
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
</Canvas>
```

How can i place this canvas on screen when i click a button for exemple ? How to create dynamically UI element from a string ?